# Open a jQuery Modal Dialog when another closes

Tags: jquery-ui, modal-dialog

I open a jQuery Modal Dialog. I open a second Modal Dialog after the first one closes. When the second one closes I cannot interact with my page any more. Seems that there is some modal dialog still alive.
Can someone help?
Thanks

```
    function modalFirst_Set() {
    $('#modalFirst').dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        dialogClass: 'DynamicDialogStyle',
        resizable: true,
        draggable: true,
        modal: true,
        width: 400,
        height: 120,
        title: "My First Modal",

        open: function (type, data) {
            var Page = 'PageFirst.aspx';

            $('#modalFirst').load(Page);
        },

        close: function (event, ui) {
            var retValue = $('#modalFirst_RetValue').val();
    if (retValue=='X')
        modalSecond_Show();
            $(this).dialog('destroy');

            modalFirst_Set();
        }
    });
}

function modalSecond_Set() {
    $('#modalSecond').dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        dialogClass: 'DynamicDialogStyle',
        resizable: true,
        draggable: true,
        modal: true,
        width: 400,
        height: 120,
        title: "My Second Modal",

        open: function (type, data) {
            var Page = 'PageSecond.aspx';

            $('#modalFirst').load(Page);
        },

        close: function (event, ui) {
            $(this).dialog('destroy');

            modalSecond_Set();
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

No problem with this code. The problem was inside the pageSecond.aspx file.